# 2 column uniqueness on both way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `friendship` model that stores the id of 2 `user`.

```
user_id  friend_id
  1          2
  3          4
```

I would like to prevent the below entries. Where user `1` & `2` are already defined in a relationship. Therefore adding another entry such as `2` & `1` should be avoided.

```
user_id  friend_id
  1          2
  2          1
```

I have tried the following but not exactly what I wanted. It only ensures that a user can't add the same friend twice.

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"

    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :friend_id
    validates_uniqueness_of :friend_id, scope: :user_id

    validate :check_friend_and_user # prevent user trying to add him/herself as friend.

    def check_friend_and_user
      errors.add(:friend, "can't be the same as user") if user == friend
    end
end
```

Comment: the way your data is structured, i would assume that when you add friends you would actually create 2 entries in the friendships table. otherwise querying friends would become cumbersome. if you really need that to be uniq, you could have another column as a workaround that holds something like `"#{lower-user-id}-#{higher-user-id}"` and make that uniq

Comment: What would be the best way for such relationship model? To create two entries? Or single entry, but when I query I would have to look under both `user_id` and `friend_id`